# Copying boost::array<char> to std::string

Tags: c++, string, boost, iterator, stdstring

I am trying to cvopy `boost::array<char>` to `std::string`.

```
boost::array<char, 1024> _buffer;
std::string data;
std::copy(_buffer.begin(), _buffer.begin()+bytes_transferred, data.begin());
```

which is not working. So I changed it a little bit.

```
char _buffer[1024];
std::string data;
std::copy(_buffer, _buffer+bytes_transferred, data.begin());
```

second one is not working either.

Comment: So what exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [back_insert_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator). Assigning to it will call `push_back` function of the underlying container so you don't need to worry with allocating space manually.

```
std::copy(_buffer.begin(), _buffer.begin()+bytes_transferred, std::back_inserter(data));
```

Comment: While this works, I think it's much less efficient than just using the constructor.  I doubt the compiler is smart enough to realize that it can optimize this into a block memory copy.

Comment: @templatetypedef I agree. I posted this for completness sake, I guess.

Answer (score 14):

The issue here is that `copy` assumes that space already exists for the data you're writing; it doesn't create any new room for you.  Consequently, both of the above pieces of code cause undefined behavior, since you're going to be copying characters to a location where space hasn't previously been reserved.

The best way to do this would be to use the `string` constructor:

```
boost::array<char, 1024> _buffer;
std::string data(_buffer.begin(), _buffer.end());
```

or

```
char _buffer[1024];
std::string data(_buffer, _buffer + 1024);
```

This will initialize the string as a copy of the data stored in the array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So Do I need to `reserve()` If I want to use `std::copy` ? and why doesn't `std::copy` crash ?

Comment: @DiproSen- No, `reserve` will not fix this.  You would need to `resize` the string so that there was sufficient space before using `std::copy`.  `reserve` serves a totally different function.  As for why there's no crash, I have absolutely no idea.  It's undefined behavior, which means that the program can do anything.  Not crashing is perfectly legal by the C++ spec.